# Puppet Create user profile on local machine

Tags: windows, puppet

I am trying to build a puppet manifest to add an ldap user profile to a local machine on the domain.

After spending some time looking through Google and various sites all I am seeing is examples of local users only and I wonder if it is even possible?

Currently I have to logon onto the computer, which creates the user profile folder under (c:\Users{username}). I need to add 3-5 profiles to every machine, but I don't want to go through the whole LOGIN > LOGOUT > LOGIN > LOGOUT process for each user on each machine.

I am new to puppet and just not sure if this is possible in puppet or if I need to figure out a different method?

Comment: I faced same problem but ended with powershell script which was creating users for me and performing logon via RDP to create folders for target user.